# How can I find out who is trying to connect to my MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I have a MongoDB server that I recently configured to allow only SSL connections. Now my mongo.log is filled with this:

```
2017-05-30T17:39:24.528+0000 I NETWORK  [conn7881820] AssertionException handling request, closing client connection: 17189 The server is configured to only allow SSL connections
2017-05-30T17:39:25.053+0000 I NETWORK  [conn7881821] AssertionException handling request, closing client connection: 17189 The server is configured to only allow SSL connections
2017-05-30T17:39:25.592+0000 I NETWORK  [conn7881822] AssertionException handling request, closing client connection: 17189 The server is configured to only allow SSL connections
2017-05-30T17:39:25.593+0000 I NETWORK  [conn7881823] AssertionException handling request, closing client connection: 17189 The server is configured to only allow SSL connections
2017-05-30T17:39:26.369+0000 I NETWORK  [conn7881824] AssertionException handling request, closing client connection: 17189 The server is configured to only allow SSL connections
```

Unfortunately the IP address of the offending process isn't logged.

How can I find out what IP is trying to connect to my MongoDB?

Answer (score 1):

The IP address will be logged by default.

For example, the following log entry you shared shows activity for the connection with an ID of `conn7881820`:

```
2017-05-30T17:39:24.528+0000 I NETWORK  [conn7881820] AssertionException handling request, closing client connection: 17189 The server is configured to only allow SSL connections
```

Prior to this log line, there will be a log line that shows the establishment of this connection. The log line should look something similar to the following:

```
2017-05-30T17:39:24.528+0000 I NETWORK [initandlisten] connection accepted from SOME_IP_ADDRESS:PORT #7881820 (SOME_# connections now open)
```

The number following the IP address will match the connection ID (without the conn portion) of the log lines in question, (i.e. #7881820)

Note: The log line I fabricated above is using the same timestamp of the log messages you provided; in reality it should be earlier in time.

Comment: Yes! grep -command is your friend. 'grep '#7881820' /var/log/mongo/mongod.log

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to get the IP address by [bumping up the MongoDb logging level](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.setLogLevel/).  I'm not sure if the *network* component logs IP address.  If not then look (or get someone with the permissions to look) [at your firewall and network logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947943/how-can-i-see-if-a-machine-tried-to-connect-to-my-linux-server-or-not) to see who's pecking away at your MongoDB listening ports.